# How long micrometer stores data in memory?

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I integrate Prometheus with my spring boot application. The metrics are exposed to Prometheus via micrometer. If Prometheus is down (it is not pulling the metrics data) and after 2 mintues I restart Prometheus, but I can see all the data within this down time period in Prometheus time-series graph. So even if Prometheus was not pulling data, micrometer must storing those data in memory.

My question is, how long will it keep storing data if the data is not pulled. And also, can I configure this manually?

Answer (score 0):

Premise of your question is a bit incorrect: if Prometheus "missed" some scrapes, this data will not be obtained. Prometheus scrapes metrics that are present on the metrics page, and associates them with the time of scrape. <sup>1</sup>

Most likely you've been deceived by [staleness](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness): when you are requesting data Prometheus returns you last actual data from within last 5 minutes, if it exists. <sup>2</sup> Thus, if your instance of Prometheus was down for two minutes, you wouldn't see area of absence of metrics, since it will be "swallowed" by staleness.

Micrometer in turn stores and exposes only metric values that are current for every time series.

---

<sup>1</sup> : Prometheus' format of metric allows to expose metric for specific time, and thus some exporters can theoretically backfeed metrics from "missing" scrapes, but this is not advised, and is not used by micrometer.
<sup>2</sup> : There a couple exceptions to this, that are described in provided link. But those are out of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, how long will it keep storing data if the data is not pulled. And also, can I configure this manually?

Data is stored as long as your application is running. The prometheus endpoint being scraped or not has nothing to do with this. You can't configure this, that would defeat the purpose.

Prometheus is a pull based registry so it needs to be cumulative (not delta), see the [docs](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_supported_monitoring_systems). Cumulative registries mandate using a running total for counters (hence the word cumulative). This means that if you increment a counter every time you receive an http request and you get 5 requests per minute, at the end of every minute you should see this in the cumulative case:
1st: 5
2nd: 10
3rd: 15

This means that you need to store the value of the running total as long as your application is running and that's why it is not a problem if Prometheus fails to scrape every once in a while.